# Datetime is not recognizing values on Python

Tags: python, date, datetime, variables, time

I am trying to define a variable with a date using the datetime function on Python. I have three variable with year,month, day:

```
year = str(l[0:4])
month = str(l[7:9])
day = str(l[9:12])
```

If I plot the variable with print(year, month, day) they are shown on screen normally. However, it is not identified if I try to define a time variable with datetime:

```
dateevent = datetime.date(year, month, day)
print(dateevent)
```

Nothing is shown on screen. Does someone know what is wrong there?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @cottontail said; you are passing strings instead of integers, it should throw an exception. This works:

```
dateevent = datetime.date(int(year), int(month), int(day))
```

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thanks. Do you know if its possible compare the dates with julian days? For example, year = str(l[0:4]), jday = str(l[12:16]), dateevent = datetime.date(int(year), int(jday))